# How to make NUMPAGES show 1 less page?

Tags: ms-word

I want the field NUMPAGES in MS Word to show the total page number of my document, minus exactly 1 page. I am trying to change the code with Ctrl+F9, but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

Comment: Ctrl+F9 gives you a pair of braces for your field (inserts a blank field). Alt+F9 lets you toggle display of field codes so you can edit them. These are slightly different on a Mac. Here is a list of shortcuts for dealing with fields from my website: http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#Function

Answer (score 4):

Use a field coded as:
{={NUMPAGES}-1}

**Note:** The field brace pairs (i.e. '{ }') for the above example are all created in the document itself, via Ctrl-F9 (Cmd-F9 on a Mac or, if you’re using a laptop, you might need to use Ctrl-Fn-F9); you can't simply type them or copy & paste them from this message.

Comment: The key is to press Ctrl+F9 to get the { }  - you are not allowed to type those in.  Thanks for that!

Answer (score -1):

```
{={ NUMPAGES \* MERGEFORMAT }-1}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.